# capture v4l : no capture device - but Video Capture Multiplanar?

Tags: linux, driver, v4l2, image-capture

I would like to capture images from a camera. I used the usual v4lgrab example (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/media/uapi/v4l/capture.c.html) but fail.  I get a message that it is not a capture device.

Taking a closer look it is  "Video Capture Multiplanar"
Try to read about but don't understand. Also I am new to V4L, so can someone give me a hint how to go on?

```
v4l2-dbg -D
Driver info:
        Driver name   : mxc-isi-cap
        Card type     : mxc-isi-cap
        Bus info      : platform:32e00000.isi:cap_devic
        Driver version: 5.4.24
        Capabilities  : 0x84201000
                Video Capture Multiplanar
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
```

Do I undestand it right, it is a device driver issue, nothing to deal with sensorchip?

Comment: It seems API for multiplanar is different: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/media/uapi/v4l/planar-apis.html